# node_save creating 2 nodes from external script

Tags: 7, nodes

This is my custom code for creating a node from some arbitrary data - this is executed in the browser from a different website by executing localhost/submit.php - the contents are below:

```
 <?php

    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', "C:\wamp\www\mydrupalsite");
    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

    $bodytext = "Foo bar";

    $node = new stdClass(); 
    $node->type = "article"; 
    node_object_prepare($node);     
    $node->title    = "A new node sees the light of day";
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; 
    $node->uid = 1;    
    node_save($node);

    ?>
```

This results in 2 nodes being created even though I've just hit the script once in the browser. Can anyone see what's wrong with this?

The output gives me 2 nodes (both have different nids) and they have identical data.

Comment: drupal version?

Comment: fresh install of drupal 7

Comment: I tried your code and there is nothing wrong with it. I think there is something wrong in your submit.php. Maybe this code gets triggered twice?

Comment: that entire code above is my submit.php - I'm pressing enter on it in the browser at localhost/submit.php and then it's getting executed twice (so it seems) - is there any way to debug this?

Comment: Code looks ok, perhaps something in your drupal install is duplicating the node on save, e.g a node api hook or Rule. Otherwise, the script may be being called twice. In any case, it's odd you're using a standalone script like that, you would be better to use the standard Drupal API and make it a menu callback in a module.

Comment: David - I'm inserting data from an external php application so I have to insert $_POST data into my Drupal site as nodes - this has to happen in real time so I don't see any other way

Comment: @Garry: Your requirements don't contradict what David said. Your could define a menu callback using `hook_menu()`and this callback could accept POST data as good as your custom strip. For debugging, you could write to the log using watchdog to see how often your code is triggered and even see from where it comes, just dump the whole request information into the log.

Comment: ah right I've not looked at it from that perspective - are there anything links you have so I can read up on it? I'm just going to google "hook_menu()" now

Comment: @Garry: You can have a look at this: http://websmiths.co/blog/very-quick-introduction-drupals-hookmenu-and-hooktheme

Comment: thanks berliner I'm unsure how I could use this to sync up $_POST data though - if a form is submitted on a different site on my server - can you actually send it to the page that you've created in your custom module - and then it can node_save it to the db?

Comment: Have you ever found why node_save is creating 2 nodes in your case? I have the exact same problem of multiplication of nodes, and I can't find why...